# What happens in reaction of Lead and concentrated Nitric Acid?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have two oppsing information, one that it forms a protective layer of $\ce{PbO}$ and doesn't reacts,other that it forms lead nitrate.Can someone clarify. **NB the acid is cc.**

Answer (score 3):

According to the CRC Handbook of Chemistry and Physics 41st edition, lead "dissolves" in nitric acid. As is the case with other unreactive metals like copper and silver, nitric acid acts as both an acid and an oxidizing agent, and dissolves the metal with formation of the metal nitrate and evolution of nitrogen dioxide.